# delete button not working todo list DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I swear I scoured the forum for a solution, but I honestly just started learning Javascript a few days ago so I am not very good at deducing solutions from different code and using the logic on my own. Total noob I am.

I want my delete button to delete the item it is assigned to when clicked. I do not understand why my deleteMe() function doesn't do anything.

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var listItem = document.querySelectorAll("li");
var dlt = document.getElementsByClassName(".delete")


function deleteMe() {
    dlt.addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.removeChild();
    })
}


function delButton(parent) {
    var del = document.createElement("button");
    del.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Done!"));
    parent.appendChild(del);
    button.className = "delete";
        }




function addToggle() {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
}

function addEntry() {
    if (input.value.length > 0 ) {
    var newItem = document.createElement("li");
    newItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(newItem);
    input.value="";
    newItem.addEventListener("click",addToggle);
    delButton(newItem);
                }
    }


for ( var i = 0 ; i < listItem.length; i++) {
    listItem[i].addEventListener("click", addToggle);
    delButton( listItem[i]);
    }


button.addEventListener("click", addEntry);
input.addEventListener("keypress", function() {
    if ( event.keyCode === 13 ) {
    addEntry()}
});
```

I would really really appreciate if someone could explain what I am doing wrong. 
Thank you!

Comment: The function is never being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dlt` is currently an HTMLCollection, not an element, so you can't add an event listener to it. Either select an element from it first (such as through iteration), or even better, assign the listener to the *container*, and have the listener check to see if the clicked target's className is `delete`. I would add the listener to the `ul`, just once, near the beginning of your script:

```
ul.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // e.target represents the clicked element
  if (e.target.className !== 'delete') return;
  e.target.parentElement.remove();
});
```

If you wanted to assign a separate listener to each `delete`, you would have to add the listener inside `delButton`, like so:

```
function delButton(parent) {
  var del = parent.appendChild(document.createElement("button"));
  del.textContent = 'Done!';
  button.className = "delete";
  button.addEventListener('click', () => button.parentElement.remove());
}
```

Comment: ahh, i see. i still get a bit confused between HTML collections and elements, so thank you for clarifying that! that really makes this exercise more accessible to me. thanks so much!